# Library not found for -lfl

Tags: c++, macos, flexc++

I was using `flex` and `bison` to build a simple calculator project I cloned from Github.

But after I typed `make` in terminal, I got the following message:

```
gcc -o calc calc.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
calc.y:48:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main() {
^~~~
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lfl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [calc] Error 1
```

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: If you think the content of the Github project you cloned may be relevant, you'd be right. I'd likely start by following whatever instructions are in whatever README included in said-same.

Comment: unfortunately there was nothing in the README except for a description of what it does.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

let me guess, trying to use flex on OS/X?

Try -ll instead of -lfl

[Using Flex on OS/X](http://linux-digest.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-flex-on-os-x.html)

So yea, the flex library name on OS/X is just arbitrarily different for some reason.  OS/X is not exactly Linux, but it's pretty close.  You have some options here.

1. You can just simply have a separate build system and source files for OS/X.  Certainly Apple might like that with their pushing XCode, objective-C and not much interoperability.
2. You can build vs Linux and then engage with [Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/) and [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).
3. You can create your project using [autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html).  That's not an awesome link, learning this system is rough going, but it's a standard thing for Linux for sure. This will actually work, I find if you have the patience for it, OS/X is close enough that autotools based builds will work on it.
4. Lately, I've been turned on to [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/), which I believe to be an attempt to join the open source community and XCode.  It's kind of half 1 and 3 sorta with an emphasis on modularizing the external source and getting it compiled into a .app (via Xcode).

Comment: That was amazing and it worked... But is that a bug or something? How am I suppose to distribute cross-platform open-source C++ project using flex? Would that be more complicated than usual to write a Makefile for it?

Comment: I'll update with info with tips that may help get you started.

Comment: Thank you ... I would have never got that

Answer (score 1):

> warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'

mean that you should declare return type for main function. Place `int` in function difinition.

> ld: library not found for -lfl

flag -l mean that compiller must use `libfl.a` to build programm. As @waTeim said above, for Mac OS you can use libl.a instead, but this lib can be not exist alse. There is another way is to place

```
%option noyywrap
```

at the top of flex *.l file. In this case you can compile without additional libs.