# Fastest way to reformat millions of lines to CSV

Tags: mysql, c, bash, csv, load-data-infile

I have a text file with millions of lines that should be imported into a MySQL table as quickly as possible. From what I understand `LOAD DATA` is the best suited for this.

The data is formatted as follows, where each uppercase letter in parenthesis is a string:

```
(A)(1-3 tabs)(B)
(3 tabs)(C)
(3 tabs)(D)
(3 tabs)(E)

(F)(1-3 tabs)(G)
(3 tabs)(H)
...
```

The data thus needs to be re-formatted to CSV, where the first string of each section must repeat in all consecutive lines until the next section:

```
(A)(tab)(B)
(A)(tab)(C)
(A)(tab)(D)
(A)(tab)(E)
(F)(tab)(G)
(F)(tab)(H)
...
```

I'm considering writing a C program, but can Bash do it just as fast (and simple)? Is this problem maybe a classic one that has a very effective and compact solution?

Comment: Hmmm [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) means comma separated value.  OP appears to want a tab separated one.  Similar but with important differences to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for a Perl script; here is one for you.  Lightly tested, takes a list of filenames to operate on as command line arguments and/or reads from stdin, writes to stdout.  Assumes that the actual number of tabs does not matter, and that there are only ever one or two nonempty fields on the line.  (It will complain about and skip any line that isn't in the expected format.)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

our $left;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^([^\t]+)\t+([^\t]+)$/) {
        $left = $1;
        printf("%s\t%s\n", $left, $2);
    } elsif (/^\t+([^\t]+)$/) {
        if (defined $left) {
            printf("%s\t%s\n", $left, $1);
        } else {
            warn "$ARGV:$.: continuation line before leader line\n";
        }
    } else {
        warn "$ARGV:$.: line in unrecognized format\n";
    }
} continue {
    close ARGV if eof; # reset line numbering for each input file
}
```

You *might* be able to write a C program that beats this for speed, but it's going to be more work than it's worth.  A shell script (bash-specific or otherwise) will be *orders of magnitude* slower.

Comment: Would using only one regex match for `/^([^\t]*)\t+([^\t]+)$/` and checking whether `$1` has length zero be faster, or would it just be an overoptimization?

Comment: @lserni That might indeed be faster (and simpler) but I don't have time right now to make up a proper benchmark to find out.

Comment: Current lead with 5.5 seconds. Added `elsif (/^$/) {;}` for empty lines. Code is easily readable even with little Perl experience.

Answer (score 3):

Try this little awk script

```
awk -F\\t+ -v OFS=\\t '$2==""{next}$1!=""{a=$1}{$1=a}1'
```

It assumes that there are no tabs in the second field.

Taking it piece by piece:

```
-F\\t+        Set the column separator to a sequence of one or more tabs
-v OFS=\\t    Use a tab to separate columns on output
$2==""{next}  Skip this line if it just has one field.
$1!=""{a=$1}  Save the first field if it is specified
{$1=a}        Replace the first field with the saved one.
              The assignment forces the line to be recomputed using OFS
              to separate columns, so it's needed even if we just did a=$1.
1             awk idiom, equivalent to `{print}` (or `{print $0}`).
```

Comment: (1) Is `-F\\t+` universal, or is it a gawkism? (2) What's the function of the 1 at the end of the script?

Comment: @zwol: (1) It's standard (FS is a regex). (2) It's the equivalent of `{print}`, but 6 fewer characters. I could have written `{$1=a;print}`

Comment: Yeah, FS is a regex, but is it universally a regex that understands `+` and `\t`?

Comment: @zwol: Take a look at Posix: "The awk utility shall make use of the extended regular expression notation (see XBD Extended Regular Expressions) except that it shall allow the use of C-language conventions for escaping special characters within the EREs, as specified in the table in XBD File Format Notation ( '\\', '\a', '\b', '\f' , '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v' )" (Search for "Regular Expressions" in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

Comment: I don't trust POSIX for tools as old as `awk`, especially considering that several proprietary-UNIX vendors froze their default shell and utilities circa 1992.  Unfortunately I am not finding an online searchable copy of the 1988 edition of "The AWK Programming Language".  The 1997 O'Reilly "sed & awk", which I was able to find, indicates that at least _some_ POSIX ERE features were not available in older awk implementations, and is unclear about whether that affects `+` or `\t`.

Comment: @zwol: In any case, it is definitely not a gawkism. It works in all the awks I have kicking around, including the version of `original-awk`  which claims to be the 1988 version. IIRC, the ERE feature not universally available was the `r{n,m}` repetition notation; gawk has a flag which turns that feature on or off.

Comment: I tested the solution with `gawk`, `mawk` and `original-awk` and it works but there is the problem of not handling the empty lines as expected. Code should be: `'$1 {a=$1} {$1=a} $2'`. Or `'$1!=""...$2!=""'` in case there's a `0` in `$1`.

Comment: @JamesBrown: Oh, I missed the blank line. Quite right. I'll fix it. (The perl solution also doesn't work with blank lines; it generates an error message for each one.)

Comment: @rici: 7s for 3m lines. Would it be possible to 1) skip lines containing certain strings (eg. "ABC" and "DEF"), and 2) do CRC32 on the second column, without losing too much of the impressive brevity?

Comment: @forthrin: a CRC32 computation isn't just moving the goalposts. It's playing in a different league. It is certainly not amenable to an awk solution. Ignoring lines is reasonably easy; just change the `1` at the end to whatever condition you want (eg. `! /ABC|DEF/`).

Comment: @rici: In that case, the CRC can be done as a separate pipe.

Comment: @rici: `gawk` 4 seconds, and `mawk` 2 seconds! Given the threshold of learning flex and compilation as a necessity, this may seem like the overall best solution after all!

Comment: Why is it that when I see an `awk` script in 2016 I suddenly feel like it's 1986? Throw in a pipeline with `sed` and I'll have to queue up the *Back To The Future* theme. :-)

Comment: @peterrowell: Even in 1986, pipelining awk into sed was considered ridiculous. And how do you feel about C? Unix? :-)

Comment: Eh ... sort of like they are newcomers. I'll admit C is better than BCPL, but I think I preferred SAIL/Tenex/PDP10 to C/Unix/PDP11-XX or Intel-anything. Of course all of that + $4 will get me a latte, so I'll just brew another batch of Russian Imperial Stout and drown my sorrows. Oh wait! That's what we did this afternoon! :-)

Comment: @rici I finally got around to going over to the university library and grabbing their paper copy of "The AWK Programming Language".  Turns out you're right: `\t` and `+` were always accepted in awk's regular expressions.  (`{m,n}` notation, on the other hand, is not mentioned either with or without backslashes.)

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness, here's a really simple "C" (actually flex) solution, which might be closer to the fastest solution.

#### file: tsv.l

```
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault
%x SECOND
%%
  char* saved = NULL;
\t+            BEGIN SECOND;
[^\t\n]+       free(saved); saved = malloc(yyleng + 1); strcpy(saved, yytext);
<*>\n          BEGIN INITIAL;
<SECOND>.*     printf("%s\t%s\n", saved, yytext); BEGIN INITIAL;
```

Compile with:

```
flex --batch -8 -CF -o tsv.c tsv.l
gcc -O3 -march=native -Wall -o tsv tsv.c -lfl
# On Mac OS  X, change -lfl to -ll
```

I tested this, the awk script in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438585/1566221 and the perl script in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438587/1566221 on a sample input of 1,000,000 non-blank lines containing 91,073 stanzas separated by blank lines. In total, the file has 201,675,114 bytes. Timings on an Ubuntu 14.04 system:

- flex: 0.85 seconds
- awk: 1.40 seconds
- perl: 3.85 seconds

In all cases, that's the user time as reported with `time prog < test.text > /dev/null` , taking the minimum of five runs and rounding off to units of 0.05 seconds.

I modified the perl script to ignore blank lines, by enclosing the loop body after the `chomp;` command in an `if (length) { ... }` conditional. It made very little difference to the execution time, but it was necessary to avoid having to ignore the warnings generated.

I don't usually use the "speed" flags on flex programs, but in this case it does actually make a significant difference; without them, the flex program took almost 2 seconds, significantly more than the awk script.

Comment: Worth testing with `mawk` as it usually provides a significant speed boost over `awk` in cases like these.

Comment: @JohnB: Yep, mawk is indistinguishable in runtime from my flex solution. (at least with just a few trials).

Comment: @rici: Compilation on OS X gives `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable`. How to fix?

Comment: @forthrin: add `-lfl` to the gcc command. Sorry. Added it to the answer.

Comment: @rici: Make that `-ll` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298097/library-not-found-for-lfl).

Comment: @forthrin: os x can be annoying. You might be able to speed the awk version up by installing a faster awk (mawk if you can find it for os x, otherwise gawk.)

Comment: @rici: Wow: 1 second! The clear winner! However, introducing a simple pipe `grep -v ABC` doubled the total time to 2 seconds. Would the same penalty occur in flex? And how about the CRC32?

Comment: @forthrin: adding the check for /ABC/ is likely to add a second on any platform, yes. For the crc, i think you can find a crc library for c easily enough. If it applies to the second field, that will be `yytext` in the line with the `printf`. But that is really a separate question and bear in mind that SO considers the question "which library should I use" as out of scope. (Once you select a library and try to use it, you can ask for help.)

Comment: Presumably, you could check for "ABC" using `strstr` which would be faster than a regex (again, on yytext) but it is not clear to me that that really covers your requirements, since they seem to be in a state of flux.

Comment: @rici: I tried a C implementation, which of course was the quickest. Could you help out at extracting the strings properly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a C implementation. About 1s for 3m lines. However, `sscanf` apparently treats whitespace indifferently and my C is a little rusty. How do I extract the strings correctly without lots of code?

```
if(line[0] == '\t') {
  // TODO: remove preceding `\t{3}` and trailing `\r`
  printf("%s\t%s\n", one, line);
}
else {
  // TODO: split at \t{1,3} and remove trailing `\r`
  sscanf(line, "%s\t%s", one, two);
  printf("%s\t%s\n", one, two);
}
```