# C error with Flex: type specifier missing?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

Running the code below in iTerm2 bash. Code file was created using Vim.

```
/* just like Unix wc */
%{
 int chars = 0;
 int words = 0;
 int lines = 0;
%}

%%

[a-zA-Z]+  { words++; chars += strlen(yytext); }
\n         { chars++; lines++; }
.          { chars++; }

%%

 main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  yylex();
  printf("%8d%8d%8d\n", lines, words, chars);
}
```

I ran commands

```
$flex fb1-1.1
$cc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

This is the error that it returns

```
fb1-1.1:17:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
  [-Wimplicit-int]
main(int argc, char **argv)
^
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lfl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see       invocation)
```

EDIT: Works now. Changed the main() to

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Also ran changed -lfl to -ll

```
$flex fb1-1.1
$cc lex.yy.c -ll
$./a.out
this is a text
^D
1   4    15
```

Comment: `main` is a function. Functions must have a return type specified. Seriously, why so many questions have this exact same problem? Who's teaching this archaic C dialect?

Comment: `int main`. But also you're missing the flex runtime library, so your program doesn't link!

Comment: On the flex distro that comes with Mac OS, you have to link with `-ll` instead of `-lfl`. But it's way easier to avoid the problem by putting `%option noyywrap` at the beginning of the flex file. Then you don't need any library.

Comment: found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298097/library-not-found-for-lfl)

Comment: thanks rici. also edited the program to ' int main(int argh, char **argv) ' but now there is no output in the bash? @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembled from comments (because it was easier than finding a dupe):

1. In modern C (that is, C from this century), all functions need a return type and the only two legal prototypes for `main` are:

   ```
   int main(void)

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   ```

   An obsolescent way to write the first is `int main()`.
2. On Max OS, the flex distro doesn't include `libfl.a`. It comes with `libl.a`. So use `-ll` instead of `-lfl`. But much better is to avoid the problem by telling flex not to require `yywrap` by putting the following declaration in your prologue:

   ```
   %option noyywrap
   ```

   Even better is to use the following:

   ```
   %option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault
   ```

   `noinput` and `nounput` will avoid "unused function" warnings  when you compile with warnings enabled (which you should always do). `nodefault` tells flex to not insert a default action, and to produce a warning if one would be necessary. The default action is to echo the unmatched character on stdout, which is usually undesirable and often confusing.

Comment: @antti: In a definition, `()` and `(void)` mean exactly the same thing (sect. 6.7.6.3p14). And `main` cannot be declared without a definition. So I've become convinced that `int main() {…}` is just fine :) Two of three examples in the standard use `int main()`.

Comment: thanks. how does MacOS interpret './a.out' ? my commands aren't giving me errors anymore so I run '.a.out' after them but nothing is printing. Im expecting an output but my bash sits there until I hit  ^C

Comment: @rici yes, but `int main()` does not *declare* a prototype. This means that the compiler is not required to do constraint checks for recursively calling `main` ;)

Comment: @user: it's waiting for you to type something, followed by an end-of-input (control-z/control-d deoending on OS).

Comment: @antti: i don't believe that is correct. A definition is also a declaration. " An empty
list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
function has no parameters."

Comment: @rici definition is a declaration, but `int main() { ... }` is not a declaration *with a prototype*. It is just a definition of a `main` function that has no parameters. I've written about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41805712/918959).

Comment: @antti: Well, clang and gcc seem to agree with you about that.