# LEX - /usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -ll

Tags: compiler-errors, lex

I am trying to execute a lex and a yacc file with `gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll -ly` but it keeps saying 
*/usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

I've tried to update flex/bison uninstall and install again but it doesn't change anything

Comment: With flex, you may need to use `-lfl`. But the best is to avoid the need.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47498990/1566221) for how to avoid the need for `-ll`/`-lfl`. You don't need `-ly` unless you don't have a `main` function; you should have one.